# Program opens file but is unable to write nor read from it

Tags: c++, windows, file

I was unable to access files in a program and drafted (mostly copied and pasted) a segment for testing doing so- just to troubleshoot.

```
fstream file;
file.open("thishere.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Managed to open file" << endl;
    file << "Here's some info for muh file\n";
    cout << "Attempted to give info to file, read: " << endl;
    string line;
    while ( getline (file,line) )
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
} else cout << "Failed to open file" << endl;
```

The program returns `Managed to open file \n Attempted to give info to file, read:`  and stops there. There is text already in the file to read off of and it does not return anything. Also nothing new appears on the file.

So it manages to neither write down information on the file, nor read information from the file, even though it is supposedly open. When I delete the file from the directory my program says `Failed to open file`. I've heard of IDE's using the wrong directory so I manually used the EXE in the directory I wanted and got the same results. I have permissions to the file, and am running the EXE as administrator.

What am I missing?

I'm using Windows 8 if that's pertinent

## EDIT:

I solved my own problem if anyone cares, it was only half the code. There was no file.close() so the file did not save. Kenny Orstroms answer also solved my problem of no text appearing. All good now!

Comment: It probably didn't exist the first time you tried openning it, but since you're using `std::fstream` with default open mode `ios::in|io:out`, it was created (as empty). Thus you can't read anything from it. This entire thing likely stems from `thishere.txt` you think you're opening exists isn't what you *actually* opened. Now there are two; one empty, one never opened. That said, moving to the directory where it is, and running your exe with that as the cwd (assuming no chdir calls) *should* work, but make sure it is the *right* file.

Comment: And fyi, Visual Studio uses the *project folder* (where the .vcprojx file lives) as the default startup working directory when run from the IDE unless you manually change it in run-time configuration settings.

Comment: You wrote stuff, then tried to read from the end. There's nothing there after where you wrote it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom To fix: `file.seekg(0);` between writing and reading.  He might also `file.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::end );` before writing, to append.